# SQL Retrieving FIRST occurrence in a time-frame

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to retrieve only the very first Process dated transaction for each User ID in this designated time-frame that was within 1 year of the purchase_date.

From what we have:

```
User ID     Transaction Purchase D  Process Date
ZZ1316567   11004463720 10/4/2018   3/9/2020
ZZ1316567   41004401606 10/4/2018   1/9/2019
ZZ1316567   41004413203 10/4/2018   5/10/2019
ZZ1316567   41004447152 10/4/2018   10/23/2019
ZZ1316567   41004462755 10/4/2018   10/23/2019
VV1454366   41004457424 4/27/2017   12/11/2019
VV1454366   51004365427 4/27/2017   8/10/2018
VV1454366   11004401749 3/24/2017   12/20/2018
SS1456449   41004315438 3/24/2017   10/31/2017
SS1456449   41004323671 3/24/2017   12/14/2017
SS1456449   41004329229 3/24/2017   1/15/2018
SS1456449   41004356097 3/24/2017   6/11/2018
SS1456449   51004292754 3/24/2017   6/7/2017
SS1456449   51004334495 3/24/2017   1/15/2018
TT1474544   11004409317 6/30/2017   4/14/2019
TT1474544   41004428284 6/30/2017   8/7/2019
```

This:

```
    Select *

    From (
        Select Distinct USER_ID, Transaction, Purchase_date, Process_date
        Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY USER_ID ORDER BY Transaction) AS Uniqueness
        From Table1
        Where Purchase_date between DATEADD(YEAR,-4,GetDate()) and GetDate() 
        AND Purchase_date < DATEADD(year, 1, process_date)
    ) As Z

    Where Uniqueness = 1
```

What I want is it restricted to THIS as these BELOW are the only transactions from the list that had their transactions process date within 1 year of the purchase date and were first among those transactions even if there was another one for the same user within that time-frame i.e. exclude ANY and EVERYTHING that does not fit this criteria:

```
User ID     Transaction Purchase Date   Process Date
ZZ1316567   41004401606 10/4/2018       1/9/2019
SS1456449   51004292754 3/24/2017       6/7/2017
```

What am I missing? Am I going about this wrong?

Comment: Your logic cannot return multiple rows for a single user.

Comment: The initial logic does because of the unique transaction ID

Comment: . . Regardless of the other columns, `ROW_NUMBER()` should return only one "1" value for each `USER_ID`.

Comment: You're right, i checked my actual query... i've also corrected my question :)

Comment: `ORDER BY Process_Date`

Comment: Side note -- I'm pretty sure `distinct` is rendered pointless by `Where Uniqueness = 1`.

Comment: I've edited the initial question to give further insight. i hope it helps any potential answers

Answer (score 0):

You can do with `row_number` as well

```
select 
    user_id,
    Transaction,
    Purchase_date,
    Process_date
From (
        Select 
            Distinct USER_ID, 
            Transaction, 
            Purchase_date, 
            Process_date
            Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY USER_ID ORDER BY cast(process_date as date)) AS Uniqueness
        From Table1
        Where Purchase_date between DATEADD(YEAR,-4,GetDate()) and GetDate() 
        AND Purchase_date < DATEADD(year, 1, process_date)
) val

where Uniqueness = 1
```

Comment: This is not returning ONLY the very first Process dated transaction for each User ID in this designated time-frame that was within 1 year of the purchase_date

Answer (score 0):

In cases where you only want the first 'n' records to be returned, outer apply () is very nice.  This syntax is T-SQL:

```
select distinct
    t.UserID,
    x.[Transaction],
    t.PurchaseDate,
    x.ProcessDate

from
    Table1 t
    outer apply
        (select top 1
            [Transaction],
            t1.ProcessDate
        from
            Table1 t1 
        where
            t1.UserID = t.UserID
            and datediff(day, t1.PurchaseDate, t1.ProcessDate) <= 365
            and t1.PurchaseDate between DATEADD(YEAR,-4,GetDate()) and getdate()
        order by t1.ProcessDate
            ) x
where
    x.[Transaction] is not null
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query to get the information.

- We are applying Partition by UserId -> to get at userId level
- We are applying Order by two clauses:

  - DATEDIFF(year, PurchaseDate,ProcessDate) = ensures that less than one year is ordered first
  - DATEDIFF(day,PurchaseDate,ProcessDate) = ensures that less number of days is ordered first

```sql
SELECT UserId, Transaction, PurchaseDate, ProcessDate
FROM
(
SELECT UserId, Transaction, [PurchaseDate],ProcessDate, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY DATEDIFF(year, PurchaseDate,ProcessDate),DATEDIFF(day,PurchaseDate,ProcessDate)) AS rnk
FROM ProcessTable) AS t
WHERE rnk = 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your efforts and this LOOKED like it would be the right answer. However, i'm having the same problem where it is pulling process dates that are greater than 1 year apart from the purchase date in the last 5 years. It IS however satisfying the condition of pulling only one row per buyer. 

Anything else you can think of?